# How can I rename a file, do something and then name it back again?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I need to write a batch file which will rename a file *.exe.config to Web.config then I need to do something to Web.config and then I need to rename it back to the original name. How can I do that? There should only ever be 1 file that matches *.exe.config and if there are more then it is ok to fail.

```
SET original= ??
rename *.exe.config Web.config
:: Do my thing here
rename Web.config %original%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the original filename:

```
for %%i in (*.exe) do set original=%%i
```

(assuming, there is only one file, that matches)

Comment: You're welcome. As a rule, you should use quotes around filenames, in case there are any spaces: `rename "Web.config" "%original%"`